# run-time error -2147417848 (80010108): method 'cells' of object_'Worksheet' failed

Tags: vba, runtime-error

I created a form to write data inside a table. I got an error every 3 times that I push the button to add data to the table. The error said: **run-time error -2147417848 (80010108): method 'cells' of object_worksheet failed**. Below you can find the code related to the button to add data to the form.
When I debug the error the code row highlighted is always this one:
**.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) = MaxId**

I hope that someone could help me with that

```
Private Sub cmd_BillingAddNewBiilingItem_Click()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim IdColumn As Range
    
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("db_billing_items").ListObjects("tbl_billing_items").Range
    Set IdColumn = Worksheets("db_billing_items").ListObjects("tbl_billing_items").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    
    Dim IdToLoad As Long
    Dim RowToLoad As Long
        
    Dim WshContract, WshOda As Worksheet
    Dim rngContract, rngOda As Range
    Dim ContractToLoad, OdaToLoad As String
    
    Set WshContract = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("db_contracts")
    Set rngContract = WshContract.ListObjects("tbl_contracts").Range
    Set WshOda = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("db_oda")
    Set rngOda = WshOda.ListObjects("tbl_oda").Range
        
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    Dim MaxId As Double
    
    LastRow = rng.Find(What:="*", _
    After:=rng.Cells(1), _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    Lookat:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    MatchCase:=False).Row
    
    If IdColumn Is Nothing Then
        
        MaxId = 1
        
    Else
    
        MaxId = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(IdColumn) + 1
        
    End If
          
    If (cbo_Billing_Client_Name = "" Or cbo_BillingCategory = "" Or txt_BillingAmount = "" Or txt_BillingInvoiceDate = "" Or txt_BillingObjectDescription = "" _
        Or txt_BillingItemDescription = "" Or txt_BillingItemName = "") Then
        
        MsgBox Prompt:="One or more mandatory fields are missing", Buttons:=vbCritical, Title:="Incomplete purchase order data"
    
    Else
               
    With rng.Parent
                   
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).NumberFormat = "0"
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) = MaxId
        
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Value = txt_BillingItemName.Value
        
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 3).NumberFormat = "@"
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 3).Value = cbo_BillingCategory.Value
        
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 4).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 4).Value = txt_BillingAmount.Value
        
        If txt_BillingStartDate <> "" Then
            
            .Cells(LastRow + 1, 5).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            .Cells(LastRow + 1, 5).Value = DateValue(txt_BillingStartDate.Value)
        
        End If
                
        If txt_BillingEndDate <> "" Then

            .Cells(LastRow + 1, 6).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            .Cells(LastRow + 1, 6).Value = DateValue(txt_BillingEndDate.Value)
        
        End If
        
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 7).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 7).Value = DateValue(txt_BillingInvoiceDate.Value)

        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 8).NumberFormat = "@"
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 8).Value = txt_BillingObjectDescription.Value

        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 9).NumberFormat = "@"
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 9).Value = txt_BillingItemDescription

        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 10).NumberFormat = "@"
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 10).Value = cbo_Billing_Payment_terms.Value

        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 12).NumberFormat = "@"
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 12).Value = txt_BillingInvoiceNumber.Value

        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 14).NumberFormat = "@"
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 14).Value = cbo_Billing_Client_Name.Value
        
        If cbo_Billing_Contract_Name <> "" Then
            
            ContractToLoad = cbo_Billing_Contract_Name.Value
            
            RowToLoad = rngContract.Find(What:=ContractToLoad, _
            Lookat:=xlWhole, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Row

            .Cells(LastRow + 1, 15).NumberFormat = "0"
            .Cells(LastRow + 1, 15).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(rngContract, RowToLoad, _
                Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("id_contract", WshContract.ListObjects("tbl_contracts").HeaderRowRange, 0))
        
        End If
        
        If cbo_Billing_Oda_name <> "" Then
            
            OdaToLoad = cbo_Billing_Oda_name.Value
            
            RowToLoad = rngOda.Find(What:=OdaToLoad, _
            Lookat:=xlWhole, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Row

            .Cells(LastRow + 1, 20).NumberFormat = "0"
            .Cells(LastRow + 1, 20).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(rngOda, RowToLoad, _
                Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("id_oda", WshOda.ListObjects("tbl_oda").HeaderRowRange, 0))
        
        End If
        
        End With
        
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        
        Unload Me
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `LastRow` when the error happens?

Comment: Hi LastRow takes always the value of the next available row within the table. So imagine that you want to add an item and that the table already has 250 rows, LastRow will take the value of 251

Comment: And have you checked with the debugger that it is really the number you expect?

Comment: Yeah there is no problem with the last row it works fine. As I mentioned the macro runs fine 3 time and then the error shoes up but apparently there is no reason.